Cannot remove liquidity from Uniswap on Base Chain
I would like to seek assistance for this please. I think the LP for my token broke after renouncing the contract. No one was able to trade after the renounce. will give 0.05 eth to anyone who can help as I would still need to refund the holders. Thank you. Token is on Base:
0x0dF0E09C90Ec9192665C6c702D67DF654C5Ef996
Error info:
-after renouncing the contract, no one was able to trade but trade is still open.
-on uniswap v2, remove liquidity, upon importing the pair, it says "not-found" but it appears in the pool list.
-clicking the pair from the pool list, percentage to pull lp appears as {{{pct}}}% instead of 25% 50% 75%
